Range.Formula2 returns "Text not Recognized" Error
I'm using the code below to put a formula in the end of K columm:
Dim Ulinha as Double
Ulinha = Planilha6.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Planilha6.Range("K" & Ulinha).Formula2 = "=SUM($K$11:K" & Ulinha - 1 & ")"
Planilha6.Range("K8").Formula = "=K" & Ulinha

But when I run this code, the cell affected shows a "Text not Recognized" error. If I select this cell and click enter on the keyboard, the error go away and the formula works fine.
My excel is in portuguese language if it makes any diference.
TKS
I tried to put this code at the end, but didn´t works anyaway:
Planilha6.Range("K" & Ulinha).Calculate


Ulinha should really be Long not Double, though I don't think that is actually your issue. Does it work if you use: Planilha6.Range("K" & Ulinha).Formula2R1C1 = "=SUM(R11C:R[-1]C)"
